# Every time when i open Xcode it gives error for Facebook SDK and g+ SDK file not found?

Tags: xcode

Every time when i open Xcode it gives error for Facebook SDK and g+ SDK file not found? When i delete previously added sdk and add again for both errors get removed ?Any solution